# Is there a function to parse a POSIX timezone and validate it?

Tags: c, parsing, timezone, posix, validation

I have timezones in the format of

```
NZST-12.00:00NZDT-13:00:00,M10.1.0,M3.3.0
```

or

```
CET-1CEST,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/3
```

is there a function or library to parse and validate them in C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because code like the C library does so.  So, there are at least three open sources for such code:

1. GNU C Library
2. *BSD C Library
3. Olson Time Zone Database

Nowadays, the Olson code can be found at IANA under https://www.iana.org/time-zones as `tzcode2017a.tar.gz` and as `tzdata2017a.tar.gz` for the data (or via FTP at ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/releases/tzcode2017a.tar.gz — and the data as ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/releases/tzdata2017a.tar.gz).

Once upon a long time ago, the code used to be at ftp://elsie.nci.nih.gov/pub — for example, in the file `tzcode2011h.tar.gz` (the time zone information is in `tzdata2011h.tar.gz`).  These old releases are available from IANA too if desired.

The version number in the file names changes periodically; the prefix stays the same, but the year (2011 vs 2017) and the release (`h` vs `a` — and there were many releases in each year in between 2011 and 2017) within the year varies over time.

Comment: well, I was reading the source of gnu libc, particularly the source for tzset. Parsing is done in __tzset_parse_tz, but this function is far from being usable from a program...